# Dpkg/atop daemon error

Tags: bash, package-management, dpkg, troubleshooting

Whenever I try to install any package the following error occurs after a small bit of working normal:

```
penguin systemd[1]: atopacct.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
penguin systemd[1]: Failed to start Atop process accounting daemon.
dpkg: error processing package atop (--configure):
installed atop package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
atop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try to install packages by opening deb files through chrome:

```
Error while installing package: installed atop package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

The error used to include something about the "atop accounting daemon," but that bit left after I updated.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot/fix this, so any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `/var/lib/dpkg/info/atop.postinst` file with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
exit 0
```

make it executable: `chmod +x /var/lib/dpkg/info/atop.postinst`

Then run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt install atop
```

If it doesn't work, replace the content of `atop.postinst` with:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/true
```

Comment: The first example works, thanks!

Comment: @PING Don't forget to accept my answer